# FATAL EXCEPTION for AndroidRuntime when starting the app for a period of time and lead to crash

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, hashmap

I have an android app running on Android 4.4.2 device. And open the app for around 10 mins and it leads to crash as following error message. But there is no clue about my code so that it makes me difficult to debug it. Anyone can provide some possible solutions?

```
11-30 12:15:47.016 8689-9472/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-106
    Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 8689
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.HashMap.secondaryHash(HashMap.java:350)
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:404)
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:95)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:380)
        at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collecti
11-30 12:15:47.256 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 0
11-30 12:15:47.256 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize dvmMinimumHeapSize 0
11-30 12:15:47.256 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize dvmMinimumHeapSize set minimumSize 0
11-30 12:15:47.336 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize Dalvik_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_nativeMinimumHeapSize 4194304
11-30 12:15:47.336 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize dvmMinimumHeapSize 4194304
11-30 12:15:47.336 8689-8689/com.xxx.xxx E/dalvikvm: heapsize dvmMinimumHeapSize set minimumSize 4194304
```

When starting this app, it will start scanning the bluetooth packet and process a series of action. I am not sure it would be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverFlow when there's a recursive call that doesn't have a base condition. A function keeps calling itself until the time that there is no more space on the stack

could you please provide the code of

> it will start scanning the bluetooth packet